# I want to group and remove values from a query with union

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

```
Select
  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_dest_cnpj_cpf,
  Count(Distinct pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_nnf) As destinadas,
  Sum(0) As emitidas
From
  pnf_notas_processadas
Group By
  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_dest_cnpj_cpf
Having
  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_dest_cnpj_cpf In ('03846642000102',
  '03846642000285', '03846642000447', '03846642000528')
Union
Select
  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_emit_cnpj_cpf,
  Sum(0) As destinadas,
  Count(Distinct pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_nnf)
From
  pnf_notas_processadas
Group By
  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_emit_cnpj_cpf
Having
  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_emit_cnpj_cpf In ('03846642000102',
  '03846642000285', '03846642000447', '03846642000528')
```

result:

[image]

My expectation for the query

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One method is to do the aggregation in one step.  However, you need somehow to aggregate along two fields.

Here is a method.  Essentially, the rows are "doubled" and then the aggregation pulls out the right values:

```
select (case when which = 1 then np.pnf_notas_dest_cnpj_cpf else pnf_notas_emit_cnpj_cpf end) as cnpj_cpf,
       count(distinct case when which = 1 then np.pnf_notas_nnf end) as destinadas,
       count(distinct case when which = 2 then np.pnf_notas_nnf end) as emitidas
from pnf_notas_processadas np cross join
     (values (1), (2)) as v(which)
where np.pnf_notas_dest_cnpj_cpf In ('03846642000102', '03846642000285', '03846642000447', '03846642000528')
Group By cnpj_cpf;
```

Comment: sorry, I did not know

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted the query

```
select (case when which = 1 then  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_dest_cnpj_cpf else  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_emit_cnpj_cpf end) as cnpj_cpf,
       count(distinct case when which = 1 then  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_nnf end) as destinadas,
       count(distinct case when which = 2 then  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_nnf end) as emitidas
from  pnf_notas_processadas cross join
(values (1),  (2)) as v(wich)
where  pnf_notas_processadas.pnf_notas_dest_cnpj_cpf In ('03846642000102', '03846642000285', '03846642000447', '03846642000528')
Group By cnpj_cpf;
```

but returned this error

select sentence invalidates unexpected element "2" on line 5 , position 16

Comment: Please don't add additional information as an answer. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39580428/edit) your question instead